# How can I target an interface for the GraphQLResolver generic?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, graphql, graphql-java

I want to use an interface (FieldTemplate in my case) as the generic type for GraphQLResolver, but it seems I'm stuck with only the work-around below due to the way the library seems to be looking for more "concrete" types (NumberFieldTemplate, TextFieldTemplate, etc. in my case). Any ideas how I create a simplified version of the below? Ideally, I'd like to express this as just one Spring Component using the interface: FieldTemplate. By the way, the code below is in Kotlin.  I'm using the graphql-java library.

```
@Component
class NumberFieldTemplateResolver :
  FieldTemplateResolver<NumberFieldTemplate>(), GraphQLResolver<NumberFieldTemplate>

@Component
class TextFieldTemplateResolver :
  FieldTemplateResolver<TextFieldTemplate>(), GraphQLResolver<TextFieldTemplate>

@Component
class LabelFieldTemplateResolver :
  FieldTemplateResolver<LabelFieldTemplate>(), GraphQLResolver<LabelFieldTemplate>

@Component
class ComboBoxFieldTemplateResolver :
  FieldTemplateResolver<ComboBoxFieldTemplate>(), GraphQLResolver<ComboBoxFieldTemplate>

@Component
class CheckFieldTemplateResolver :
  FieldTemplateResolver<CheckFieldTemplate>(), GraphQLResolver<CheckFieldTemplate>


abstract class FieldTemplateResolver<T : FieldTemplate> {
  fun screenBox(fieldTemplate: T, displayUnit: DisplayUnit?): ScreenBox = when (displayUnit) {
    DisplayUnit.PIXELS -> screenBoxInPixels(fieldTemplate.screenBox)
    else -> fieldTemplate.screenBox
  }
}
```

My GraphQL Schema looks something like this...

```
interface FieldTemplate {
  id: ID!
}

type NumberFieldTemplate implements FieldTemplate {
  id: ID!
  ...
}

type TextFieldTemplate implements FieldTemplate {
  id: ID!
  ...
}

...
```

Comment: currently facing the same issue. Did find any solution ?

I'm also trying to solve the problem with graphQl Union type.

Comment: Hi Paul, no unfortunately I never found a solution.  If you figure something out with your union type idea, I’d also be curious to hear.